# Can Alcubierre Space Drive function in space time within event horizon of a Black Hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, event-horizon, warp-drives

[Alcubierre Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive) compresses space in front and propagates as such but in a singularity where space is untraversable is propagation possible? If so can you prove it?

Comment: This question is unclear. Are you asking if the Acubierre drive can propagate past the event horizon? Within the event horizon? Across the singularity itself?

Comment: Yes as spacetime dictates it should be stationary in space (towards singularity) but the alcubierre drive works by expanding and contracting space .What i want is a confirmation that it is useless in singularity.

Comment: I think the answer is yes. Problem is that Alcubierre drive is contradictory even theoretically. EH inside is just a thing what no one has seen until now.

Answer (score 0):

No,unfortunately a Singularity is basically the region where General Relativity fails to hold, therefore the laws of General Relativity and ultimately the principles on which Alcubierre  Drive is based on will collapse.

Comment: I think the question is more meaningful if we interpret it as asking from the EH. Although probably the OP ist not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I would say no, as in the area of a singularity, time and space swap places.  It would be like racing in any direction trying to escape Tuesday.  You can't.

Comment: Singularity and event horizon are different things.